# How to smoothly scroll through 600ish uilabels on a big uiscrollview (iphone)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview, uilabel

I have a bit gantt chart that i want to be visible on an iphone.

It is 7200 x 1800px large, and consists of ~600 bars, each of which is a UILabel.

It is to look like this:

[image: Gannt]

Now i've gotten it to work. And at ~100 bars, i can make it run quite smoothly by simply adding them all to the scroll view. However, with the full 600 (or more eventually) it simply crashes when i instantiate all those uilabels and add them all to the scroll view as subviews.

So what i've done is made it create only the uilabels for the currently visible rows, and as the user scrolls up and down it removes the invisible uilabels and adds the newly visible ones.

However, this jerks quite noticeably as you scroll vertically as it crosses each row boundary, and has to render another row and remove the old row.

Does anyone have any suggestions to solve this? Any ideas what is the slow part? Instantiating the uilabels, or adding them as subviews, or anything?

All help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've tried pooling the hidden labels as they scroll off, and re-using them so as to save on allocing the newly visible ones, but it doesn't speed things up much.

Comment: It could be memory issue ,Is your cell autorelease ?

Comment: Have you tried just moving the labels instead of hiding them?

Comment: Tried prepping a page full at any given time so effectively you have 3 pages online at any given time? (x-1), x and (x+1)?

Comment: Hi warren, yes that's my current approach. Works well, until you hit the top of x-1 or bottom of x+1, when it has to load another page, which chugs for half a second.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple has some really good demo code that shows how to do this. Check out [TiledScrollView.m](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/ScrollViewSuite/Listings/3_Tiling_Classes_TiledScrollView_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008904-3_Tiling_Classes_TiledScrollView_m-DontLinkElementID_26) especially the `layoutSubviews` method.

Other things you might consider:

- If you labels are quite long horizontally you may need to break them into smaller chunks. Quite long in this context is wider than the screen.
- Make sure your UILabels are opaque. Scrolling things that require compositing adds extra overhead which may account for some of your issues.
- Looking at your screen shot the row and column headers are not opaque and are using alphas. Whereas this is a nice effect it may be worth temporarily making them opaque too just to see if this is contributing to your problems. I don't think this is contributing too much to your problems; the area being composited is quite small.

Comment: The idea is to build a sort of table view out of the scroll view that now recycles image tiles (or labels, in your case) instead of cells. The scroll view is subclassed and a set of reusable tiles is kept as one of its instance variables. As noted by @idz, the key to the implementation is, in `layoutSubviews`, to remove from superview the tiles that have moved out of the visible area, then recycle tiles for newly visible content and add them as subview. In this way, only visible tiles are loaded into memory...You should check out this demo; Apple gives you the full code to make it fast+smooth.

Comment: @Chris, You're welcome! I've used it to do something quite similar to what you are doing. In my case it had to work on an iPad (as well as iPhone) so there were a lot more labels visible at a time. It really works nicely.

Comment: Yup, in the end i've gone for a similar approach to apple's and it's working quite well. Thanks for the tips!

Answer (score 1):

Just a thought, but could the issue be that even though you are caching and reusing the labels, is the scroll view still retaining them, so even though you may only have a few labels, each is being retained hundreds of times. If this is so then I would think that the scroll view is still effectively trying to manage those hundreds of rows.

So as @Nathon S asked - are you moving them? i.e. building a finite set of labels and just moving them around on the scroll view to match the viewing area. If you are hiding and re-adding to the scroll view then I would suspect a massive set of retains being the slow down. I would think that with a moving label design, you would not need to do any hides and adds after the the initial display. Which should make it very fast and lightweight.

Comment: I've tried both - adding and removing them from the scroller (storing them in a 'pool' array before removing), as well as trying simply moving them around. Both are quite slow.

Comment: ok, I don't have the experience with this to know, so this might be completely wrong :-) but have you checked that all the "moves" are done in the same animation block? I remember reading something about it in relation to graphics performance.

Comment: Hi Derek, there's no animation block, i'm simply letting the uiscrollview do its normal scrolling